# Why this query is not working and says Invalid Column name

Tags: sql, select, sybase, union-all

```
SELECT ROUND(K1,2)
FROM (SELECT '5.66666' UNION ALL
      SELECT '5.77777' UNION ALL
      SELECT '5.88888' UNION ALL
      SELECT '5.99999' UNION ALL
      SELECT '6.66666' UNION ALL
      SELECT '7.66666' UNION ALL
      SELECT '8.66666' UNION ALL
      SELECT '9.66666' UNION ALL
      SELECT '9.55555' UNION ALL 
      SELECT '6.88888' AS K1) K
```

Error says `Invalid Column name 'K1'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column alias in a `union [all]` structure comes from the **first** query, not the last one. Move your alias there, and you should be OK:

```
SELECT ROUND(K1,2)
FROM (SELECT 5.66666 AS K1 UNION ALL -- Here!
      SELECT 5.77777 UNION ALL
      SELECT 5.88888 UNION ALL
      SELECT 5.99999 UNION ALL
      SELECT 6.66666 UNION ALL
      SELECT 7.66666 UNION ALL
      SELECT 8.66666 UNION ALL
      SELECT 9.66666 UNION ALL
      SELECT 9.55555 UNION ALL 
      SELECT 6.88888) K
```

Comment: Now it is saying that Function `Round is invoked with wrong no of arguments.`

Comment: @AnkitBajpai The **number** of arguments seems right, but your query was using string literals instead of numerical literals. See my edited answer.

Comment: @Mureinik,Perfect answer.

Answer (score 0):

Give column name for the first record, then it will take the same name for rest for records.

```
SELECT ROUND(K1,2)
FROM (SELECT '5.66666' AS K1 UNION ALL
      SELECT '5.77777' UNION ALL
      SELECT '5.88888' UNION ALL
      SELECT '5.99999' UNION ALL
      SELECT '6.66666' UNION ALL
      SELECT '7.66666' UNION ALL
      SELECT '8.66666' UNION ALL
      SELECT '9.66666' UNION ALL
      SELECT '9.55555' UNION ALL 
      SELECT '6.88888') K
```

Comment: Now it is saying that Function `Round is invoked with wrong no of arguments.`

Answer (score 0):

Give alias name for first row of first column or give alias name for all rows 
of first column :

```
   SELECT ROUND(K1,2)
   FROM 
   (
      SELECT '5.66666' AS K1 UNION ALL
      SELECT '5.77777' AS K1 UNION ALL
      SELECT '5.88888' AS K1 UNION ALL
      SELECT '5.99999' AS K1 UNION ALL
      SELECT '6.66666' AS K1 UNION ALL
      SELECT '7.66666' AS K1 UNION ALL
      SELECT '8.66666' AS K1 UNION ALL
      SELECT '9.66666' AS K1 UNION ALL
      SELECT '9.55555' AS K1 UNION ALL 
      SELECT '6.88888' AS K1
    ) K
```

Comment: Now it is saying that Function `Round is invoked with wrong no of arguments.`

Comment: @AnkitBajpai,Check your query.Above query is working fine.Post your last tried query here.